# CKeditor : notification called from dialog isn't displayed at foreground

Tags: ckeditor4.x

In CKeditor4, I have tried to show a notification when the dialog is opened at first time but the notification is displayed behind the dialog box. Is-there a way to show the notification at foreground ?

This is my code in the dialog part :

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'MypluginDialog', function( editor ) {
    return {
        title: 'my plugin title,
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        contents: 
        [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',
                label: 'Dialog settings',
                elements: 
                [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'title',
                        label: 'My title',
                        default: ''
                    }                   
                ]
            }
        ],
        onOk: function() {
                        
        
        },
        onShow: function() {
             var notification1 = new CKEDITOR.plugins.notification( editor, {
                message: 'Error occurred',
                type: 'warning'
             } );
             notification1.show();      
        }
    };
});
```

So how to display the notification not behind the dialog box ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Notifications can be displayed in front of any dialog after adjusting their `z-index` CSS property, for example (*`!important` needed since it has inline `z-index` style already*):

```
.cke_notifications_area {
  z-index: 10050 !important;
}
```

Keep in mind that dialogs and notifications `z-index` value depends on CKEditor 4 [`baseFloatZIndex` configuration option](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-baseFloatZIndex) (which is `10000` by default) so if this configuration option was changed you need to adjust CSS accordingly.

Please also keep in mind that [Notification](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/notification) plugin is not really intended to be displayed over dialogs since it works in a way that it's positioned related to editor editable area (and dialog is not) and may display on the bottom part of a dialog or some more unexpected places (depending on editor position).

See this [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/GRqVbrZ).